# Use jsp variable in jquery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page that loads other pages into a modal div. I am not able to get a variable recognized in the other pages. I am sure the problem is quite simple to solve, any help?

Here is the variable page1 in the main page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.page.SelectPage" %>
<% SelectPage page1 = (SelectPage)request.getAttribute("page"); %>
```

I have a simple modal div defined

```
<div class="container modal" id="mymodal"  style="height:70%"></div>
```

When someone click on a link I load the modal using jquery.load

```
<a class="btn btn-outline modal-trigger" onclick="modalNavigate('mytopic');">Single Modal Navigation</a>

<script>
function modalNavigate(navPage){
    $("#mymodal").load(navPage + ".jsp");
}
</script>
```

However when the navpage is loaded the variable page1 is not recognized

Comment: where do you invoke this `modalNavigate()`?

Comment: Its attached to a button to start the process. After that it will be attached to links contained in the modal page to load another page into the same modal.                                                                          
                       <a class="btn btn-outline pink accent-3 modal-trigger" onclick="modalNavigate('b3tztopic');">Single Modal Navigation</a>

Comment: Kindly edit your post with that additional code for better help.

Comment: Actually the real problem is not being able to access the request attribute of the parent window from inside the modal loaded by jquery.load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `request.getAttribute("page")` loses its scope when you use `$.load()` as it leads to another request.

Option 1. Just use session instead of request to get the `page` object.

Option 2. Using $.ajax instead of $.load with additional parameters from `request page object`.

Answer (score 0):

Do an ajax request to the server, return the data to the JSP and in success of AJAX request add the data to the modal popup.

Comment: `$.load()` does exactly the same thing

Comment: I am using the embedded java variable page1 to get access to the server across all the modals. I would like to have that access so I do not have to make a series of ajax calls and process the results into objects.

Comment: The problem is page1 is not in scope for the results of the $.load()